# Why is there an error when i change argument of "EventArgs" to "FormClosingEventArgs"

Tags: c#, eventargs

In Program.cs, Argument *EventArgs* changed to *FormClosingEventArgs*

```cs
private void Exit_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {   }
```

In Program.Designer.cs, Change in *Program.cs* lead to an error at Line.9

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Exit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.Exit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(839, 275);
        this.Exit.Name = "Exit";
        this.Exit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 112);
        this.Exit.TabIndex = 0;
        this.Exit.Text = "Exit";
        this.Exit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.Exit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Exit_Click);     //ErrorPart
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 12F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1020, 399);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Exit);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
```

> Exisi an error CS0123: No overload for 'Exit_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'.

Everytime when I start debug this will be show to me, I using Visual Studio 2017,What's is the problem overthere.....?

Comment: A button click handler has a specific signature, you can't just replace one parameter with something else and expect it to still work

Comment: `Exit` is a `Button` not a `Form`, why should the click event take a `FormClosingEventArgs`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `Click` handler of a `System.Windows.Forms.Control` does not take argument of type `FormClosingEventArgs`, rather it takes `EventArgs` which needs to be passed like this

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   }
```

> In simpler words, it's like assigning a `string` value to an `int`
>   variable

For more information see this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx